# Is requestIdleCallback scheduled for standardization?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is `requestIdleCallback` [1], as implemented in Chrome 40, scheduled for standardization?

[1] https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-requestidlecallback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a W3C working draft that covers it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-requestidlecallback-20150929/).  This means that someone (the author is Ross McIlroy from Google) is attempting to solicit feedback, explain why it is useful and hopefully make it into a standard, but it is not yet.

One cannot necessarily infer from the fact that a working draft exists whether or not it will eventually become an adopted and implemented standard.  Time will tell.

Per [this July 2015 post](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514656), there is public support for the concept from Firefox, mixed signals from Microsoft and no public signals about Safari.

Per this [September 2015 post](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5572795866021888), there is public support from Edge and Firefox.

Some public discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/_0ZwVT4UFvU) which surfaces an open issue about whether this should return a promise rather than take a callback.

There is a [Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1198381) about implementing `requestIdleCallback` in Firefox, though it is really just serving as a tracker for the issue - there does not appear (in that bug) to be a plan to implement it yet.

---

**Update as of Nov 2015:**

The working draft is implemented in desktop Chrome 47, Chrome for Android 47, Chrome for iOS 47 and Android WebView 47.  Public support expressed from both Edge and Firefox, though no specific "intent to implement" yet from them.

Comment: Even better, it is now "Proposed Recommendation" see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback#Specifications